# capacitive contribution voltammetry

Tags: electrochemistry, cyclic-voltammetry

I am working with a sheet of zinc metal where there is an oxide film on it (ZnO) in passivation conditions (pH=10). I have done voltammetry measurements for different scan rates with a 3 electrodes configuration, with zinc sheet as the working electrode. I would like to quantify the capacitive current. How should I process ? How to compensate the iR drop ? What is the crossing point in my curves ?

Thank you [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq8z1.jpg)